# ISO some kind of latch that releases due to rotational forces or G forces

Tags: mechanisms

I am working on building a device that 'throws' an object similar to how a human would throw using similar mechanics, but can throw the object much farther than a human. My device functions more like a human arm and less like a spinning wheels which shoot the object out (which would be much easier).

The goal is for a human to to use device to enhance the power their arm can already generate.   If your arm is like a whip throwing a ball, now instead of holding a ball in your hand, instead hold this device which can extend the 'whip' which is then holding the ball.

The problem I've hit is that a human knows when to release the object near the aim point, but my device so far is not consistent in that.  Too loose and the ball comes out early, or too tight and the ball doesn't get released.

I have my throwing device set up to add various pressures to the object it is throwing and 'grip' the object, but getting it consistent is very difficult.  Just when I think I've fine-tuned one aspect of it, something else changes and I need to start over again.  It's quickly looking to me like trying to use friction and throwing the object quick enough to overcome that friction isn't working.

Is there any kind of mechanical switch and that can open some kind of latch when a certain rotational force is hit?   Even better if it were adjustable so it can be fine-tuned for different throwing speeds?

I've tried my Googling on the topic, but it's kind of a tricky search term.  Does such a switch or latch exist?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you're overthinking it.  Look up what an "atlatl" is. Atlatl do not have release mechanisms either (that's not to say they don't require skill). When you draw inspiration when designing something, you have to be careful that the details you are copying aren't unnecessary and increase complexity.

Comment: ISO = International Standards Organisation?

Comment: @DKNguyen  Thank you for the reminder to keep it simple. You got me thinking how I could incorporate in some principals from an atlatl. I'm still stuck on throwing object with a high rate of spin. Say it's a boomerang. Can't just push it through the air quickly. I'm in a spot where I can generate consistent spin, just stuck on the release. With more simple methods I keep getting stuck on how to move the object with using a loose grip/support instead of fully gripping it.  I don't think mimicking how a clay pigeon launch works because the throwers won't throw with the correct motion needed.

Comment: @Transistor ISO = In Search Of

Comment: It's better to write for an international audience many of which don't have English as their first language. Spell it out!

Comment: @user3644787 A gradual ramp that lets the tool swing past the ball as they leave each other might be enough for a spin. That's kind of what baseball players do. I think the spin is put on the ball after the ball is released and is flicked afterwards. Like maybe a flexible backing thing that moves backwards under the inertia of the ball to let the tool swing past the ball as it leaves might do it too.

Comment: re: ISO .... sounds like a personals ad

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem to me.  There are a dozen ways to release a latch that doesn't require timing of g forces.  Or get a jai alai cesta.

Comment: There is a device on the market, held in the hand like a stick, used to throw tennis balls for dogs that might be adapted for your purpose.